# Cannot compile QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, compilation

I'm trying to build QtCreator with gcc 4.7 but I'm getting the following error:
[image]

The point is that I uninstalled QtSDK and instead I've built Qt from source (but not QtCreator which I'm doing now). I've check the `PATH` variable and QtSDK isn't mentioned anywhere, yet mingw32-make is getting it from somewhere.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I appreciate you have specified gcc 4.7.. but I think its worth mentioning QtSDK **does** come with gcc but version 4.4.0 instead. Also, you must manually select it during the installation process under the advanced/custom install option.

Comment: @Styne666 why would I want to mention gcc 4.4 if it comes with qtsdk and doesn't need any manual configuration, just plug and play?

Comment: If you search for "QtCreator gcc" you could mean several things, one of which is your question. Another likely scenario is wanting to know how to build a project in QtCreator with gcc.

Comment: @Styne666 I dissagree, too many general places...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do this stuff from the README before trying to compile?

```
set QTDIR=<working_directory>\qt
set PATH=%QTDIR%\bin;<path_to_mingw>\bin;<working_directory>\creator\bin;%PATH%
set QMAKESPEC=win32-g++
```

Comment: Thanks, no I didn't. The working directory should refer to which directory?

Comment: QTDIR points to the root directory of wherever Qt is installed (either by compiling or installing from a package). The README seems to assume you have a working directory with qt and creator folders and you compile both from the same working directory.

Comment: From the readme:Create a working directory under which to check out Qt and Qt Creator,

       for example, c:\work. If you plan to use MinGW and Microsoft Visual

       Studio simultaneously or mix different Qt versions, we recommend

       creating a directory structure which reflects that. For example:

       C:\work\qt4.7.1-vs10, C:\work\qt4.7.2-mingw.

Comment: thanks, what happened was that I had makefiles from previous qmake run which was in directory QtSDK. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're interested in **Qt Creator for Windows** and there **is** a binary for that, why don't you install it this way?

http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/downloads#qt-creator